# Selenium python checkbox click() sometimes clicks submit button instead of unchecking box

Tags: python, selenium

Please bear with me since this my first Stack Overflow question. The problem is that when I step through the code, it works as intended--the checkbox is cleared and the value of the variable coupon is sent to the now-available text box. However, when I run the code, line 2 of the code below causes the browser to effectively click the "save and submit" button instead. In addition, similar lines of code for checkboxes above the below code work whether stepping through or running the code. Note: I'm using Firefox.

Below is my code:

```
IRbox = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='interest_rate']//td[@class='edit']//span//input[@type='checkbox']")
if IRbox.is_selected() == True: IRbox.click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbInterestRate')))
browser.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbInterestRate').send_keys(coupon)
```

...

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div//input[@type='submit']").click()
wait.until(EC.title_is('Report'))
```

Printing test statements after each line of code appear until after line 2. The error statement appears after line 2 has been executed because the code is looking for elements on a now previous page:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sakiyama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\MyPythonScripts\indtest - selenium.py", line 490, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbInterestRate')))
  File "C:\Users\sakiyama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

What I've tried in the script (all with the same result):

- Different combinations of finding the element
- Using sleep
- Using waits instead of sleep
- Different combinations of saving/reloading/returning to that page
- Commenting out the IRbox lines of code (still submits instead of checks/unchecks box for similar lines of code further down the page)
- Commenting out the "submit" code

HTML for code above IRbox that works:

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbIssuePrice_unknown" name="price_at_issue_unknown" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="updateUnknown(this,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbIssuePrice','');" type="checkbox">
```

HTML for code on IRbox doesn't work (though I suspect this is a JS problem):

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbInterestRate_unknown" name="interest_rate_unknown" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="updateUnknown(this,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbInterestRate','');" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: How long did you send the thread to sleep? it just sounds like elements haven't finished loading if this works when stepping through?

Comment: I tried it for 5 seconds, and before that I had one-second sleep statements interspersed for the other checkboxes (which work fine up until this one). On the suggestion of a colleague, I changed the sleep statements to waits, though that didn't fix the problem. I've noticed that as soon as IRbox is clicked (or that the command is sent to click it), the page immediately goes to the submitted page.

Comment: Where did you put your thread to sleep? Are you sure you put it at the very beginning before any selenium code is executed? The Dom elements need time to get rendered

Comment: I had it sleep upon browser.get() and at least four times after four other checkboxes preceding it, in addition to adding the 5 second sleep right  before the IRbox statements